# How to properly detect a PHAsset's file type (GIF)

Tags: ios, objective-c, gif, photos, phasset

I have no idea why this is so difficult. I'm trying to determine the file type of a PHAsset, specifically, I want to know if a given asset represents a GIF image or not.

Simply inspecting the asset's filename tells me it's an MP4:

`[asset valueForKey:@"filename"] ==> "IMG_XXXX.MP4"`

Does iOS convert GIF's to videos when saved to the devices image library? I've also tried fetching the image's data and looking at it's dataUTI, but it just returns `nil` for GIF's (I'm assuming all videos as well). I'm fetching the image data as follows:

```
PHImageManager *manager = asset.imageManager ? asset.imageManager : [PHImageManager defaultManager];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    PHImageRequestOptions *o = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    o.networkAccessAllowed = YES;

    [manager requestImageDataForAsset:asset.asset options:o resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            if(completion) completion(imageData, dataUTI, orientation, info, ciImage.properties);
        });

    }];

});
```

the dataUTI returned from the above call is `nil`.

If anyone knows of a reliable way to determine a PHAsset's file type (I'm specifically looking for GIF's, but being able to determine for any type of file would be great) let me know!

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 15):

Use PHAssetResource.

```
    NSArray *resourceList = [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:asset];
    [resourceList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        PHAssetResource *resource = obj;
        if ([resource.uniformTypeIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.compuserve.gif"]) {
           isGIFImage = YES;
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 6):

Also you can find [uniformTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phcontenteditinginput/1518675-uniformtypeidentifier) from [PHContentEditingInput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phcontenteditinginput) class. For this; use **requestContentEditingInput** function from PHAsset

Don't forget to
import MobileCoreServices for kUTTypeGif

Sample Swift 3.1 code:

```
    let options = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true //for icloud backup assets

    let asset : PHAsset = .....  //sampleAsset
    asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options) { (contentEditingInput, info) in
        if let uniformTypeIdentifier = contentEditingInput?.uniformTypeIdentifier {

            if uniformTypeIdentifier == (kUTTypeGIF as String) {
                debugPrint("This asset is a GIF")
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work from a **Photos.app Editing Extension**. I am only passed the `PHContentEditingInput` at the beginning of the session (not the asset itself), and the property `uniformTypeIdentifier` is `nil`...

Comment: This seems a bit heavy-handed because this function requests the actual image / video and prepares it for editing. And it's asynchronous, which indicates it takes some time / resources to perform.

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 3.0 and above

```
import MobileCoreServices


var isGIFImage = false
if let identifier = asset.value(forKey: "uniformTypeIdentifier") as? String
{
  if identifier == kUTTypeGIF as String
  {
    isGIFImage = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a public key?

Answer (score 3):

I guess since iOS 11, we can use:

```
if asset.playbackStyle == .imageAnimated {
    // try to show gif animation
}
```

Comment: // try to show gif animation <-- I need the info on this :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am not sure what do you mean by the GIF image. 
Are you referring to Live Photo or Time-lapse ?

However, if you want to check the current asset is Live Photo, Time-lapse, then you can check like this

```
if(asset.mediaSubtypes == PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoLive)
{
     // this is a Live Photo
}

if(asset.mediaSubtypes == PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoTimelapse)
{
     // this is a Time-lapse
}
```

for determining the generic file type of a PHAsset, you can check

```
   asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeImage 
   asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeVideo
   asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeAudio
```

Comment: He means images that are in a .gif format (animated images), not Live Photos or Time-lapses.

.png, .jpg, .gif, .tiff are all types of images. Photos on iOS can store gifs, he's asking how you detect if an image is a gif or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
//phAsset if object of phAsset

if let imageType = phAsset.value(forKey: "uniformTypeIdentifier") as? String {
    if imageType == kUTTypeGIF as String { 
        //enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation so we can clearly see your intent.